# Assign a new value within if function

Tags: python

I'm trying to a get the number of pages from a webpage and their links but for some of the webpages there is no href on the page number. So I've tried to create an  attempt on an if statement, but it still returns the error.

The aim was to say if the page count is not present then just assign it the value one. Though I'm pretty unexperienced so I'f appreciate some support on this.

It seems to fail on the seventh page:

```
final_data = []
for m in range(0, 10):
    df = {'data':[]}
    driver.get(links_countries['links'][m])
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    pages = soup.select("#yw2 a")
    pag = []
    for p in pages:
        pag.append(p.get_text(strip=True).replace('', ''))
    pag = [string for string in pag if string != ""]
    if int(pag[-1]) < 1:
        int(1)
    else:
        continue
            
    print('Page number', pag)
    href = []
    for t in pages:
        href.append(t['href'])
    href = [string for string in href if string != ""]
    urls = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + href[0]
    print(urls)
```

This output is given by replacing the if statement with `pag = pag[-1]`
Output:

```
Page number 2
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/jahrgang/0/land_id/1/kontinent_id/0/yt0/Show/0/
Page number 10
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/jahrgang/0/land_id/2/kontinent_id/0/yt0/Show/0/
Page number 10
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/jahrgang/0/land_id/3/kontinent_id/0/yt0/Show/0/
Page number 10
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/jahrgang/0/land_id/4/kontinent_id/0/yt0/Show/0/
Page number 4
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/jahrgang/0/land_id/5/kontinent_id/0/yt0/Show/0/
Page number 5
https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop/plus/ausrichtung/alle/spielerposition_id/alle/altersklasse/alle/jahrgang/0/land_id/6/kontinent_id/0/yt0/Show/0/
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-1fd034d415eb> in <module>
     10         pag.append(p.get_text(strip=True).replace('', ''))
     11     pag = [string for string in pag if string != ""]
---> 12     pag = int(pag[-1])
     13     print('Page number', pag)
     14     href = []

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: (1) `if` isn’t a function. (2) you aren’t assigning anything inside the `if` block. (3) the code you’ve posted isn’t the same as the code you’ve run, according to the error message.

Comment: It fails because `pages = soup.select("#yw2 a")` is an empty list on that page.

Comment: From `IndexError: list index out of range` I see that the list named `pag` is empty.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis is there a way to skip that url altogether, so to not take any information from that page and continue - and do the same for the rest like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the error message.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The reason why you get the above error is because your list `pag` is empty, so you cannot slice it.

If you want to skip the page, then at least use this check instead of handling the error.

```py
if pag:
    pag = int(pag[-1])
else:
    continue
```

The statement `if pag` is equivalent to `if len(pag) > 0`. However, I follow [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#214-truefalse-evaluations) so I'm going to stick with `if pag`.

Comment: What's the difference with my approach and your approach?

Comment: @me.limes Your approach worked, but it is not recommended. It is even advised not to use the `try` / `except` block that way. When handling errors, you should handle a specific error, for example, `IndexError`. Also, you should try your best to minimize the use of `try` / `except` block when there is a better alternative to prevent the error.

Comment: @me.limes TL;DR this approach **prevents** the error, while your approach **stops the error message** from showing.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to at least skip the url with:

```
try:
        pag = int(pag[-1])
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).